# Rearranging of orthonormal decompositions [Proof Verification]

Tags: functional-analysis, proof-verification, hilbert-spaces, orthonormal, schauder-basis

Let $T : H \to H$ be a compact self adjoint operator on a Hilbert space with spectrum $\sigma(T) = \{\lambda_n\}_{n \in F}$ with $F$ countable (the latter guaranteed by the spectral theorem).

I want to show that the definition of the operator
$$
\widetilde{T}x := \sum_{n \geq 1}\alpha_nP_{E_{\lambda_n}}(x), \quad \alpha \in \ell^\infty
$$

does not depend on the ordering of the eigenvalues (here $P_{E_{\lambda_n}}$ denotes the eigenspace projection).

I've argued as follows. Since $H = \bigoplus_{\lambda \in \sigma(T)}E_\lambda$, by definition we have that the space generated by the eigenspaces is dense on $H$ and these are pairwise orthogonal. Thus, is suffices to see that any reordering

$$
\widetilde{T}_\rho \ x := \sum_{n \geq 1}\alpha_{\rho(n)}p_{E_{\lambda_\rho(n)}}(x)
$$

with $\rho \in S(F)$ agrees with $\widetilde{T}$ in each eigenspace (and this is immediate from the definition of both operators).

Does this seems sound? That is, can we always that if $H$ is the hilbert sum of certain subspaces $(E_n)_{n \geq 1}$, then two operators $T,S \in \mathcal{L}(H)$ are equal if and only if they agree on each space $E_i$?

This seems true to me in the subcase of an orthonormal basis, but I'm not sure if I'm missing something when generalizing.

Comment: Is it meant to be $\ell ^2$ and not $\ell ^\infty$ in the definition of the operator?

Comment: I meant it to mean $\ell^\infty$, as $\sum_n\|\alpha_nP_{E_n}x\|^2 \leq \|\alpha\|^2_\infty\sum_n\|P_{E_n}x\|^2 = \|\alpha\|^2_\infty\|x\|^2$.

Comment: Yes that makes sense, my mistake.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $\mathcal{H} = \bigoplus_\alpha M_\alpha$ in the Hilbert space sense (the subspaces are orthogonal and the algebraic sum generates $\mathcal{H}$), then if $T,S$ are bounded operators that agree on $\forall \alpha \  M_\alpha$, then since a general element of $x \in \mathcal{H}$ can be expressed as $x = \sum_\alpha a_\alpha v_\alpha$ where the sum is at most countable, Since the operators are bounded you have 
$$T(x) = \sum_\alpha a_\alpha T(v_\alpha) = \sum_\alpha a_\alpha S(v_\alpha) = S(x)$$

So yeah, if the sum is in the Hilbert space sense, agreeeing on subspaces means agreeing on the whole space. In particular this applies to your case.

Comment: When you say *generate*, you mean that the generating set (in the algebraic sense) is dense in $\mathcal{H}$, right?

Comment: @GuidoA. Yes, the algebraic sum is dense, that's what I meant. Since they are orthogonal it's equivalent to being able to express all elements as infinite sums.

Comment: Awesome, it's what I thought (although I was working only in the countable case) but I wanted to be absolutely sure. Regarding your comment in the OP, is it a mistake to take $\alpha \in \ell^\infty$? I (think I have) shown that $\|\widetilde{T}x\| \leq \|\alpha\|_\infty$